# Emacs basic setting for scala developement: Initialization error

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am following the steps given in this [post](http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/basic-emacs-setup/) to set up my emacs environment for scala development. Here is what I have written in *~/.emacs* file:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path “~/.emacs.d/”)
(add-to-list 'load-path “~/.emacs.d/plugins/”)
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t) ;; enable fuzzy matching
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/plugins/autocomplete/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/plugins/autocomplete/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default) 
(add-to-list 'load-path
          "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
(setq frame-title-format '("Emacs @ " system-name ": %b %+%+ %f"))
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/emacs-goodies-el/color-theme.el")
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-gnome2)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/install/scala-mode2")
(require 'scala-mode2)
```

but when I start emacs I can see the following error after running it with *--debug-init* option:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable \u201C~/\.emacs\.d/\u201D)
(add-to-list (quote load-path) \u201C~/\.emacs\.d/\u201D)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/vraj11/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at $
load-with-code-conversion("/home/vraj11/.emacs" "/home/vraj11/.emacs" t t)
load("~/.emacs" t t)
#[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312$
command-line()
normal-top-level()
```

I am not able to guess what's going wrong. Please help me get rid of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string literals in the first two lines are syntactically wrong.  You need to use plain quotation marks, i.e. `"`, and not curly quotation marks.

Replace all occurrences of `“` and `”` with `"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got into this problem because of my emacs without color theme. After installing color theme support it's easier to find things like this.